# How to set Git Tag as ENV Variable in package.json Script

Tags: node.js, shell, package.json

Im trying to set the Git Tag as a Node ENV variable for my app so I can use it and display it on my React UI. For this I defined the following script:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_ENV=development VERSION=\"$(git describe --tag)\" concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
}
```

I also tried it like this:

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development VERSION=$(git describe --tag) concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
```

But the VERSION variable stayed empty.

Any advice what I need to change?

Comment: Did you try to create a .env file?

Comment: Why do I need a .env file? Im able to set the NODE_ENV variable via the script like in the example. So I thought I could do the same with a VERSION variable.

Answer (score 0):

To use a defined env variable in React you have to name it `REACT_APP_VARIABLENAME`. Except for `NODE_ENV`.

And access it via `process.env.REACT_APP_VARIABLENAME`

This worked for me.